# How to prevent 3dmouse from being recognized as standard mouse?

Tags: mouse, 3d, blender

Have an older USB 2.0 3dConnexion "Space Pilot" 3d mouse.   Have installed the `spacenavd` package, and associated drivers and config widget `spnavcfg` and can successfully ping the Daemon to verify the driver is loaded correctly.
driver is loaded.

[image]

The annoyance is that the 3dmouse, is being recognized as a regular old mouse, and moves the mouse pointer every time the 3d axis controller is touched.

The aim to is to use this 3d mouse in Blender.  System is on the most recent versions of ubuntu / blender.

What is being done wrong here?

Comment: System is on the most recent versions of ubuntu What version would that be?